# slow framerate on ios8 with spritekit

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, ios8

hi i have created a game in ios7. its working fine with a constant framerate of 60 in
 ios7.1  .Two days ago i updated my Xcode from 5.1 to Xcode gm seed6 now when i compile my game again with iOS8 many bugs occur

such as

1) framerate dramatically drown down from 60 to 45

2  zposition of  sprite not working fine

3) CGpath memory leaks

4) few crashes while compile game again and again

is xcode6 gm seed contains bugs or i have to fix these bugs myself

is anyone faces the same issues

Comment: Classic simulator performance drop?

Comment: all the testing occur on device

Comment: There is indeed something wrong in iOS8: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1045101#1045101

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this problem?

Comment: at last i found the solution of all my problem

Answer (score 1):

at last i found some solution why games are behaving slow in ios8 in compare of ios7

1)[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:<#(NSString *)#> usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
     //your code
   }] casing problem  in ios8 it's behaving slow in ios8 after talking to apple guyes they told me thats enumerateChildNodesWithName is changed is ios8 because many developers trying to change or modifying node while Enumeration that may lead to their game to crash so now due to null pointer checking  enumerateChildNodesWithName is slow in ios8 means if enumerateChildNodesWithName find any null value its will lead to a c crash.

2) for movements of parallax or objects you should use  [[self children] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
     //your code
   }]
 which is nearly taking 4 time less time than enumerateChildNodesWithName (at least in my case)

3) while dealing with physics i found thats making two many dynamic bodies leads my game slow so better solution for that is use static physics bodies  and move or deal with them inside update function or with skaction.

4)preload and save all texture as a singleton and load them higher to lower order consume less memory while saving texture as a singleton object maintain a 60 framerate

5)one thing i forget in my game that not using name for every skaction so better give a name to every skaction that would help me out to remove action manually and applying same action with on multiple nodes.